# Ajax Form Submission with out new page loading (error on IE)

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms, xhtml

Basically:

When you click login via Firefox or Chrome or Safari, the form submits as I want it to; running a validation via ajax then opening a new page.

However, in IE(x<9) the submission actually tries to post to the self page and my javascript is never called.

I don't want the page to change, just ajax to run through; the reason I use  is so that the submitted data can store with the local browser password cache.  Again it works perfect with all browsers with IE.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: I'm assuming it has something to do with ACTION=""; I through in the javascript in there and that didn't work i.e. ( action="javascript:dologin()" )

Comment: you want to post some of your codes here?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
action="javascript:dologin()"
```

Try this instead

```
action="YOUR_LOGIN_URL" onsubmit="dologin();return false"
```

Comment: That won't work since IE will literally post to the action src; that does work fine in all the other browsers.

Comment: return false; will probably prevent it from submitting, except if there's something wrong with your dologin().